# Session Variable becomes null after postback or page is refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am currently using a ASP.Net Web application, and have a login page that sets the session variable to datatable with a user's information.
After login, the user is redirected to a profile page, where the session variable is used to populate the profile page with the user's details. And that works. But whenever I try and refresh the page, the session variable returns null, and I do no know what to do to fix it. Also you should know that all the files I have for this application are in the same location.

Bellow is the Login page code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace EProject
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                
            
            
        }

        protected void btnSignin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            string userEmail = Email.Value;
            string pass = hashPassword(password.Value);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] where Email=@email AND Password = @Password", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", userEmail);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

            {
                Session["user"] = dt;
                Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
            }

            else
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private string hashPassword(string password)
        {
            SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] password_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] encrypted_bytes = sHA1.ComputeHash(password_bytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted_bytes);
        }

        protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
        }
    }

}
```

Bellow is the Profile page code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace EProject
{
    public partial class Profile : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                if (Session["user"] != null)
                {
                    DataTable dtu = (DataTable)Session["user"];
                    ViewState["user"] = dtu;
                    string UserID = dtu.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString();
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [User] where UserId=" + UserID, con);
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            FullName.Value = dt.Rows[0]["Full_Name"].ToString();
                            Email.Value = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
                            Address.Value = dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
                            Gender.Value = dt.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString();
                            DOB.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DOB"]).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                            MemberID.Value = dt.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
                }
            }

        }

        protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            Session["user"] = ViewState["user"];
            DataTable dtu = (DataTable)Session["user"];
            string UserID = dtu.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString();

            CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            string dateString;
            DateTime dateValue;
            dateString = DOB.Value;

            string n = dtu.Rows[0]["Full_Name"].ToString();
            string p = dtu.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
            string ad = dtu.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
            string d = dtu.Rows[0]["DOB"].ToString();

            if(NewPassword.Value == "")
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdUpdateProfile = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [User] SET Full_Name = @fname, Address = @address, DOB = @dob Where UserId=" + UserID, con))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MMM/yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dateValue))
                    {

                        cmdUpdateProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FullName.Value));
                        cmdUpdateProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(hashPassword(NewPassword.Value)));
                        cmdUpdateProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("address", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Address.Value));
                        cmdUpdateProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DOB.Value));
                        cmdUpdateProfile.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        Label1.Text = "Profile Edited successfully";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        Label1.Text = "Invalid Date";
                    }

                }
            } else
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdUpdateProfile = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [User] SET Full_Name = @fname, Password = @password, Address = @address, DOB = @dob Where UserId=" + UserID, con))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MMM/yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dateValue))
                    {

                        cmdUpdateProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FullName.Value));
                        cmdUpdateProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(hashPassword(NewPassword.Value)));
                        cmdUpdateProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("address", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Address.Value));
                        cmdUpdateProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DOB.Value));
                        cmdUpdateProfile.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        Label1.Text = "Profile Edited successfully";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        Label1.Text = "Invalid Date";
                    }

                }
            }
            
               
            


        }

        private string hashPassword(string password)
        {
            SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] password_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] encrypted_bytes = sHA1.ComputeHash(password_bytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted_bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Bellow is the web.config code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OasisDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

I am running the application locally..

Comment: < sessionState mode= "InProc" stateConnectionString= "tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString= "data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless= "true" timeout= "60" />This seems to be Web.Config The default configuration for Session in the file
Try changing the mode="InProc" attribute to StateServer, because this session may be a problem with the configuration file.

Comment: I have tried adding the line: <sessionState mode= "StateServer" stateConnectionString= "tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString= "data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless= "true" timeout= "60" /> into my web config file, but now I get an error any time i run any page. It says: The configuration section 'sessionState' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration. Any idea what I did wrong?